# How to make my website top ranking on Google?

Tags: google-search, search-engines, website-promotion

I am searching this question on Google but I couldn't find any suitable results. Now I am posting this question on Stack Exchange as my last options. As we all know that Google is the leading door of high traffic towards a site, I want to make my website top ranking on google. I have already submitted it to google and i i also use proper meta tags. What are the factors that make a site topranking and how to make our site pop up top in google? Please someone help me guys. Thanks In advance :)